# Connecting Sound Module (no USB option) to Audio Interface/DAW for recording and playback in MIDI

Tags: midi

I currently record midi tracks in my DAW (Reaper) by using a midi controller (NI S61)and software instruments (VST´s). I would like to add an older Kurzweil K2600r sound module to my set up. I want to be able to record and playback instruments from the Kurzweil using midi "notes", not audio WAV forms. Yes, I have an audio interface that has midi in/out options. The Kurzweil also has midi in/out/thru but not a USB connection. If this is possible can someone give me a straight forward, "connect this to that, and that to this" type of explanation on how this can be achieved? Thank you in advance for any enlightenment on this matter!

Comment: You mean you want to play MIDI out of the computer, to make the Kurzweil play sounds, then record those sounds back into the computer? or...

Comment: Well, yes.... I can "play"  and record the Kurzweil now, into my DAW, but it's audio, not midi. I was hoping there is a method that, as I am playing a Kurzweil instrument, it is recording the track in midi notes...(because the midi notes are highly editable) then when I press play in my DAW it plays back the same Kurzweil instrument. Basically I would hope to play and record the Kurzweil exactly as I can play and record (and playback) the VST´s.

Answer (score 1):

The K2600r has standard 5-pin MIDI connections (in/out/thru). You should use these on your audio interface (most audio interfaces have MIDI connections as well as USB).

Connect a MIDI cable from the 'Out' of your interface to the 'In' of the K2600r, and another from the 'In' of your interface to the 'Out' of the K2600r.

In your DAW, send the MIDI information on the MIDI channel that the K2600r is listening on, and you should be fine.

Comment: I will try these suggestions and post the results...I am wondering if it would be easier (or even work) f I had a separate midi keyboard controller (with USB) JUST for the Kurzweil module?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use the K2600r. If you want to play live, and have other stuff going on with the other controlller, then yes - but in a playback situation at home, you don't need it - the NI S61 can work. You just need to make sure you know what MIDI channels are going where.

Comment: Perfect...yes, just at home with the DAW...I'm switching out the S61 for a S88 this week plus a new audio interface. When I re-connect everything I'll try it your way and post the feedback. I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

a midi keyboard without USB can be imported by a USB midi interface (as Roland UM-ONE or an older product as midiman:

http://tr.roland.com/products/um-one/

the connection is no problem: USB to USB and midi in/out to midi in/out

Comment: Not quite.  MIDI in/out to MIDI out/in.    The MIDI OUTput of the module goes to the MIDI INput of the computer, and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry: I mean of course the two 5pin ends of the interface cable. They are signed as midi in and midi out. The other end is an USB that has to be stuck at the USB plug of the computer.

Comment: It can be confusing!  On the UM-ONE, the flying lead marked MIDI OUT needs to go to the socket on the device marked MIDI IN.     Fortunately, if you get it the wrong way round, nothing breaks.  It just won't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your Kurzweil by MIDI so that it can be controlled by a MIDI track in Reaper.  It makes no difference whether the MIDI connection is direct USB or via the older 5-pin cables.

But neither way will transfer the SOUND of the Kurzweil into Reaper.  If you want to include the Kurzweil's sound in your Reaper mixes, you'll need to connect audio out of the Kurzweil to the audio input of your computer's audio interface, and record it as an audio track.

This can, of course, be done while 'playing' the Kurzweil from a MIDI track in the same Reaper project.   But you'll have to treat it in the same way as adding another live vocal track.